# Single Direction Communication to the Future

Tags: technology, time-travel, communication

If it were possible to create a device that when its state was changed a second device would mimic the state, but many years in the future, would this serve any purpose?

Data could be transmitted from the present to the future and the past to the present but no communication could take place going back in time.

Would this be useful at all for any purpose?

**Edit 1:**

The transmitting person is able to choose how far in the future they want it to be received but can not change it once the two objects are created.

Once the set time is reached, the message is transmitted instantly, with no delay for the speed of light.

Comment: It's called books. Write something down in the past, read it in the future. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @EricJohnson Labeling the complete change in your question as "Edit 1" is a bit disconcerting. I hope there is not a second change.

Comment: So, per edit 1, If I wanted to set the delay to 1ms, I basically have faster-than-light communication?  Dang right that'd be useful!  Its only a mainstay of science fiction for trying to build galactic empires which is not known to be accomplishable using any known law of physics!

Comment: Keep in mind that with two of these and relativistic speeds, you can now create time travel paradoxes (since they are FTL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usability of your device divided by time you can set:

---

**Less than a millisecond**

Anywhere on Earth. I assume that in this case it would be adopted first by the high frequency traders: They have money to obtain such device and it would be real benefit for them.

**Less than a second**

Still almost anywhere on Earth. We would most likely use it for around the globe communication and I think we would use it as "Internet 2"

**Less than a minute**

Anywhere in the solar system. Mars comes first as great candidate to use the device.

**Less than an hour**

If the device can be set to send message to the future which is at least 30 minutes a front, then we would still use it for communication inside solar system

---

**A day and more**

The question comes to mind: *Do I know that such message is 100% delivered?*

**If yes**, you actually created indestructible device. Because if I set it to receive the message tomorrow, it means that the other pair of the device has to sit there for 24 hours and no one can destroy it.

Then the military is targeted customers for that device: We will simply use it as a shield. The first army in possession of such device is world domination power because no one can stop them.

**If no; the device can be destroyed.** Then I have bad news for you: You actually created a book. Because once we say the device can be destroyed, it means that it definitely can be opened and investigated. The level of the device being "tough to crack" then decides if we would use it as shield or as good way to say hello to our ancestors

Comment: P.S.: I wrote that from my cellphone, so my humble request for the peoples of the future is to edit the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

Write a letter to the future, put it in an envelope or box with the "Open on xyz date only."  Set aside the envelope in a place where it will be undisturbed until that date.

If it's a very distant future, engrave the message (maybe in multiple languages), with instructions on its care.

Answer (score 3):

**Nope.**

This is equivalent to writing yourself a note but you can only read it at the exact moment that you sent it to.

In either case, the device for transmitting information, be it paper or a time entangled eight-ball, needs to be kept by by whoever wants to receive the message. The paper can be copied, read at any time, and doesn't require advanced technology to decipher.

---

*Edit:*

**Yep.**

Of course we'd build the device pairs to have zero delay, anything greater than zero would not be useful except in some rare cases (mostly scientific). This would allow for instant communication across the globe and indeed across the universe. That's a very useful thing to have. Of course, sending to right now is quite different than your original question of sending to the future.

Comment: I have updated the question based on the speed of light.

Comment: @EricJohnson That's a rather radical change to your question. I'll update.

Comment: Part of the reason was also so I would not just get all answers saying it is the same as a book, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two uses for it:

1) A way to keep records secret until after everyone involved has died. Countries could require all government officials to keep logs and diaries and send them 50-100 years into the future. Hopefully, people would send more accurate reports than they publicize. The downside is that there is no way to prove what was sent, so it might turn out the be hours of nonsense.

2) Trolling the future humans. Set it to send the same two messages to many points in the future. The messages read:

1. "We have done it. We proved the Existence of God."
2. "Oh no, it is happening."

If there was no requirement for the second machine, i.e. it would be a signal that appears in the future and could be received by similar or simpler machines (radio receivers?) then a 3rd use would be to send our history and knowledge into the far future in case of apocalypse. Of course, if we use our tech to destroy the world, sending knowledge of how that tech works into the future would also be a form of trolling...

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if a record could be made such that it could not be read until that time.  Any device you build could be compromised and the note read early. If it was encoded such that it took a period of time to crack, you can only guess at how long it would take as computers keep getting faster; unless it was a short-term thing like a few weeks or months, but what's to prevent the people from deciding to invest more resources into the problem?

The only thing I can think of is using the speed of light.  You know the retroreflector on the moon? Send something like that on a space probe far away. You beam a message at it, and nobody can find out what it said until the probe receives it a d sends it back!  The probe can be very far away so that you have speed of light delay, or simply inaccessible over that period of time.  For example, if you beamed a message to the New Horizons craft with a program to play it back in 5 or 10 years, you can be pretty sure nobody will go out there to meet it in the mean time, even though that's not against the laws of physics.

Comment: I think OP wants to know if such a device would be useful, regardless of how it is actually constructed.